# How to get JQuery to swap picture prior to page being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following script which swaps the source of an image. However currently this happens after the page loads so the user experiences a split second of seeing one picture before it switches to the correct image.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var winnerName = $("#leaderboard tr td:eq(1)").text().trim();

    $("#pictureDiv img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + winnerName + ".jpg");
};
</script>
```

How can I get the image to switch before loading?

Note I've also tried:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var winnerName = $("#leaderboard tr td:eq(1)").text().trim();

    $("#pictureDiv img").attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + winnerName + ".jpg");
});
</script>
```

but this results in the same thing occurring

Comment: I am afraid Its not possible, use `css` and `html` to achieve initial state, after DOM ready you can use jQuery to do the swapping.

Comment: Try it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mq876tbL/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Both of the window.onload or jQuery's $(function()... functions are only called when the page is fully loaded.
The closest you could get is to add the function to the images onload handler.

```
<img src="..." onload="function() {...}">
```

But I suspect the same will still occur.

If the image's src needs to be set using javascript then you could try dynamically creating the image and adding it in where you need it, using something like the following.

```js
$(function() {
    var winnerName = $("#leaderboard tr td:eq(1)").text().trim();
    var imgElement = $('<img>').attr("src", "/Content/Images/" + winnerName + ".jpg");
    
    $("#pictureDiv").append(imgElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pictureDiv"></div>
```